# PaintEvent on DataGridView does not paint on the ScrollBar

Tags: c#, datagridview, paintevent

i'm trying to make a graphical enhancement/makeup to my current module. Admittedly, i like Windows 10's 1px (i think?) borders for application windows. The thing is, the facility i'm working at is still utilizing computers/laptops running Windows 7/8/8.1 Operating Systems - which i'd not fancy with their old thick-borders. So what i do is i'm recreating this UI Candy towards my WinForm-based module.

Basically, i removed the borders on my Form. Then i made use of the Paint Event Handler to paint lines with 1px on height or width. I have been successful so far, specially in stacked controls like Form->Panel->Panel - with each of them i've individually painted lines to the top, left, right, or bottom sides.

Now my next struggle is with DataGrid Control (i would also forecast that other controls with ScrollBars might have the same case) - which doesn't paint the line in the whole control. Basically, when i paint the line, it only paints it on the Grid's Cells, excluding the scroll bar on the right (probably if there's a bottom scrollbar too). I've tried looking for solutions to this but to no avail, which one solution said was to slap a panel atop the control which i think is not a good idea.

Refer to the below image for the problem i'm looking for a solution, you can notice that the DataGridView's ScrollBar doesn't seem to have had borders painted.

[image]

i would gladly appreciate if someone can lend me a hand here, thanks.

below is my code for painting the 1px border, i actually turned it into a static method so i just had to call it when needed - reducing repeated codes:

```
public static void DrawBorder(Control control, Color penColor, params BorderLocation[] borderLocations)
{
   var pen = new Pen(penColor);

   var pointA = new Point(0, 0);
   var pointB = new Point(0, 0);

   control.Paint += (sender, e) => {
        foreach(BorderLocation borderLocation in borderLocations)
        {
             switch(borderLocation)
             {
                  case BorderLocation.Left:
                       pointA = new Point(0, 0);
                       pointB = new Point(0, control.Height);
                       break;

                  case BorderLocation.Right:
                       pointA = new Point(control.Width - 2, 0);
                       pointB = new Point(control.Width - 2, control.Height);
                       break;

                  case BorderLocation.Top:
                       pointA = new Point(0, 0);
                       pointB = new Point(control.Width, 0);
                       break;

                  case BorderLocation.Bottom:
                       pointA = new Point(0, control.Height - 2);
                       pointB = new Point(control.Width, control.Height - 2);
                       break;

                  default:
                       pointA = new Point(-1, -1);
                       pointB = new Point(-1, -1);
                       break;
             }

             e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pointA, pointB);
        }
   };
}
```

and i would call it like:

```
UITools.DrawBorder(dGridWipedPhones, Color.FromArgb(76, 175, 80), BorderLocation.Right, BorderLocation.Bottom);
```

Comment: scrollbars are not part of the client area

Comment: is there any possible way i can manipulate this area/control then?